# How does Angular listen for mousedown events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the [`ngDraggable` project](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable), there is a line of code in the `ngDrag` directive

```
element.on(_pressEvents, onpress);
```

where

```
var _pressEvents = 'touchstart mousedown';
```

But I looked all throughout the code, and I don't see any `$emit` or `$broadcast` of either `_pressEvents`, `touchstart` or `mousedown`.

What's publishing these events? Is it something built into Angular?

Answer (score 1):

These are native events, they are triggered by the browser.

**Sources**:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents